# Concatenation of strings within functions

Tags: bash

I am having a weird problem with bash scripts.

I have two scripts: vlan_menu and the other network_menu.
network_menu sources vlan_menu and calls configure_v().

Inside vlan_menu, I do this:

```
function configure_v() {
    TAG_V=66
    str="team0."
    newtag="$(echo ${str}${TAG_V})"
    ${SCRIPTS}/system_config -e ${newtag} ...
    echo ${newtag} >&2
}
```

when I run vlan_menu and print the value of ${newtag}, Isee: 
"team0.66"
which is what I want to see.

network_menu:

```
source vlan_menu
configure_v;
```

When I run network_menu, the output of the echo is:
"team0. 66"

Why does this happen?
Please help.

Comment: Your error is not apparent from the snippet you have posted. If there is intervening code between `source vlan_menu` and `configure_v`, then it should be posted as well. (see the answer why using *command-substitution* with `echo` to assign a concatenated string is wrong -- well, at least, totally unnecessary)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the simpler expression:

```
newtag="${str}${TAG_V}"
```

Comment: The quotes and braces are both optional as well. `newtag=$str$TAG_V` is equivalent.

Comment: True, but I don't see how that causes the OP's problem.